# What are some of the research styles and research routines of successful researchers?

Tags: publications, research-process, mathematics

I am Phd student in CS with less than 15 published papers from which none is at a top journal or conference.
My typical research routine comprises of reading papers with potentially improvable results that published at journals/conferences that are categorized by certain sites as Q2/A, thinking about alternative solutions to these results for a few days and if I make any progress on discovering alternative improved solutions then I check if there are any newer papers citing the basis paper with similar results, if there aren't I continue investigating for a few weeks after which I usually have some publishable results.
The preparation of the paper takes significantly longer and I usually involve one more author in this step.
I generally avoid trying to read and improve results published at top journals or conferences mainly for the following reasons:

1. The papers containing these results tend to require more
   diverse knowledge in order to be read fluently than results
   of lesser publication venues.
2. These results generally receive much attention so they are more
   likely to have more able people trying to extend or improve them and
   thus it's more likely for someone else to publish results essentially
   the same as mine earlier than me
3. The published papers there tend to have a lot of authors from top
   institutions which makes it somewhat intimidating for me to try
   doing further research on their results
4. Some of the papers there seem to have been written by people who
   have worked on a very specific area of research for a very long time
   and thus have developed numerous techniques and advanced intuition which give
   then significant advantage in these areas.

I would define successful researchers as those who publish, on average, at least 3 papers every 2 years in top conferences or journals.
My question is as follows:
What are some the research styles of research routines of successful researchers?

Comment: Please mention your decipline or subject of research so that the specific experts in that subject can give you some hints

Comment: "I am Phd student in CS with less than 15 published papers" If your number of papers is anywhere close to 15, we should be asking you this question. Its rare to _finish_ a PhD with more than 5 publications, I would say.  I had 3 I think.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - well, my impression is the OP is tying up a few loose ends here and there on, well, topics of secondary (or less) importance.